# SpringBoot deployed under context path

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, apache-tomee, tomee-7

Have a SpringBoot application packaged as an EAR and deployed to a local TomEE 7 instance.

Once deployed, is hosted under a context path of `TOMEE/my-app-api`

A static index.html page in webapp folder is served correctly from TOMEE/my-app-api/index.html

I have a `RestController` with a single GET endpoint mapped to `/api/country`

When I try and call the `RestController` via `TOMEE/my-app-api/api/country` I get a 404.

If I run the same app from the embedded Tomcat instance and call the `RestController` via `TOMCAT/api/country` I get a successful response.

Is there anything additional I need to configure in order for SpringBoot to be hosted under this context path?

**EAR Gradle Task**

```
apply plugin: 'ear'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

ear {
    archiveName = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute().text.trim() + "-$version" + '-service.ear'
    baseName = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute().text.trim()
    version= "-$version" + '-service'

    deploymentDescriptor {
        displayName = 'Service API'
        webModule('service-api.war', 'service-api')
    }
}

dependencies{
    deploy project(path: ':service-api', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy project(path: ':service-data', configuration: 'archives')
    deploy project(path: ':service-rules', configuration: 'archives')
}
```

**Application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ServiceApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you configure your context path?
did you try this endpoint? TOMEE/my-app-api/my-app-api/api/country

Comment: Haven't configured any context path, just using the default currently which gets set by TomEE. Tried that endpoint without luck :(

Comment: You can configure the context path in your application.properties file as server.context-path

Comment: OK will give it a go...

Comment: Tried `server.context-path=/test-api` but made no difference

Comment: Of course, because the `server.*` properties will only be used when you use the embedded servlet container. What does the log show, when you start the application? Usually you should see entries for your RestControllers.

Comment: Logs don't seem to be generating for some reason

Comment: It's almost like application is not starting correctly

Comment: yeah, can you share maven/gradle config that generates the EAR?

Comment: Have you got a `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass in your application? You need one in a war that's deployed to a standalone container: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Comment: @Ulises have added EAR gradle task

Comment: @AndyWilkinson have added application class, does have `SpringBootServletInitializer` base class

Comment: Could it be because `service-api` and `service-data` both contain an application class inheriting from `SpringBootServletInitializer`?

Comment: @timothycliffordyou also have a section were you generate the service-api.war with the spring-boot-gradle-plugin right? (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html)

Comment: Yes I have this in my project root gradle file